# Python - breaking down the percentage of values and adding new rows to the list

Tags: python, list, txt

I'm a beginner in python and can't figure out the percentage breakdown of the amount. I would like the rows to contain lines with the calculated amounts.

DATA FROM TXT:

```
['Date', 'Period', 'NumberBill', 'Amount', 'KEY', 'WHAT\n']
['31.01.2022', '2', 'BILL3', '-1800.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL\n']
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL2', '644.00', 'PERSON','BILL\n']
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL1', '150.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL']
```

OUT_my:

```
['31.01.2022', '2', 'BILL3', '-1800.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL\n', -540.0, -360.0, -900.0]
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL1', '150.00','TEAM', 'BILL', 45.0, 30.0, 75.0]
```

I wrote:

```
filepath = "test.txt"
file = open(filepath, "r")
for i in file:
 iSplit = i.split(";")

 percentage1 = 0.30
 percentage2 = 0.20
 percentage3 = 0.50
 result1 = 0
 result2 = 0
 result3 = 0

 if iSplit[4] == 'TEAM':
     result1 = float(iSplit[3]) * percentage1
     result2 = float(iSplit[3]) * percentage2
     result3 = float(iSplit[3]) * percentage3
     iSplit.append(round(result1, 2))
     iSplit.append(round(result2, 2))
     iSplit.append(round(result3, 2))
     print(iSplit)`
```

What I want to get:

```
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL2', '644.00', 'PERSON','BILL]
['31.01.2022', '2', 'BILL3', '-540.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL]
['31.01.2022', '2', 'BILL3', '-360.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL]
['31.01.2022', '2', 'BILL3', '-900.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL]
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL1', '45.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL']
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL1', '30.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL']
['03.02.2022', '2', 'BILL1', '75.00', 'TEAM', 'BILL']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Don't append to `iSplit`. For each percentage, make a copy of `iSplit`, replace `iSplitCopy[3]` with the precentage, and append this to the result list.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post I have already corrected the visibility. Back to the topic, in that case, will I create too many additional lists? This is just a snippet, what if I have a different item and a different key and again divide into several percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result you want, you should print a new row for each percentage, with the amount replaced by the amount multiplied by the percentage, not append them all to the original row.

And to get the non-team rows, use an `else:` block to print the original row.

```
filepath = "test.txt"

team_percentages = [0.30, 0.20, 0.50]

with open(filepath, "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        iSplit = i.split(";")

        if iSplit[4] == 'TEAM':
            for percent in team_percentages:
                new_row = isplit.copy()
                new_row[3] = str(float(iSplit[3]) * percent)
                print(new_row)
        else:
            print(iSplit)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will read about Python list method. I've never used copy().